# How do you specify that you want your elements in a ToolBar to be centered?

Tags: java, layout, javafx, javafx-8

For some reason, JavaFX's `ToolBar` only proposes two options for items alignment: `LEFT_TO_RIGHT` and `RIGHT_TO_LEFT`.

And funnily enough, if this is `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` you have to specify your items in *reverse order* so that they show up naturally...

However I don't see any option for aligning elements in the *center*. How do you achieve that? Or must I use something else than a toolbar?

---

edit: here is the current code... Unfortunately this doesn't work :(

FXML:

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.github.fge.grappa.debugger.csvtrace.tabs.linechart.LineChartTabDisplay">
    <top>
        <ToolBar fx:id="toolbar">
            <HBox fx:id="hbox" alignment="CENTER">
                <Region fx:id="leftSpacer"/>
                <Button text="Refresh"/>
                <ProgressBar visible="false"/>
                <Label text="Layout testing"/>
                <Region fx:id="rightSpacer"/>
            </HBox>
        </ToolBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

the class:

```
public class LineChartTabDisplay
    extends JavafxDisplay<LineChartTabPresenter>
{

    public Region leftSpacer;
    public Region rightSpacer;
    public ToolBar toolbar;
    public HBox hbox;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        HBox.setHgrow(leftSpacer, Priority.SOMETIMES);
        leftSpacer.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        HBox.setHgrow(rightSpacer, Priority.SOMETIMES);
        rightSpacer.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    }
}
```

But this is what it gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FOUND.

In fact, the code is pretty "simple". Kind of, since this really *should* be in the `ToolBar` for starters, but here goes...

The FXML is now as follows:

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.github.fge.grappa.debugger.csvtrace.tabs.linechart.LineChartTabDisplay">
    <top>
        <ToolBar fx:id="toolbar">
            <HBox fx:id="hbox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="5.0">
                <Button text="Refresh"/>
                <Label text="Layout testing"/>
            </HBox>
        </ToolBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

And the code is simply:

```
public class LineChartTabDisplay
    extends JavafxDisplay<LineChartTabPresenter>
{
    @FXML
    protected ToolBar toolbar;

    @FXML
    protected HBox hbox;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        hbox.minWidthProperty().bind(toolbar.widthProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: and add maxWidthProperty

Answer (score 0):

Well there is this little hack to produce a dynamic spacer:

```
final Region spacer = new Region();
HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.SOMETIMES);
spacer.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

If you put one as first item and another one as last item on the  `ToolBar` your items inbetween should be centered.

Comment: So, I took it to mean that my items were to be enclosed in an `HBox`... I did that, but unfortunately the HBox doesn't seem to want to expand its width to that of the `ToolBar`'s :( If I try and bind its `.prefWidthProperty()` to the toolbar's `widthProperty()` it is completely messed up... I wonder why things which should be simple are so complicated :( See the question edit too

Comment: On my toolbar this spacer `Region` works quite well.. I am out of luck then. Did you set the `minWidth`?

Comment: The minWidth of? The HBox? No I didn't. My code is really just as you see it in the question...

Comment: The minWidth of the spacer.

Comment: Really not sure what you mean here. I just adapted your code: put a `Region` both as the leftmost and rightmost elements, and use your code to set the hgrow property and the minimum size.

Comment: Well, I found the solution anyway... Had to bind... Ahwell

Answer (score 0):

Just keep an eye on the width of the Toolbar and apply the new value to the HBox. This is necessary in order to monitor the size of the Stage

```
toolbar.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {  
    hbox.setPrefWidth(newVal.doubleValue());
});
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by explaining how this code answers OP's question.