# How to set vbox size to be minimum (wrap-content)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm new with javafx and fxml stuff, and I can't achieve to center my items in my border pane.

My fxml is the following :

```
<BorderPane ...>
    <top>
        <Label styleClass="page-title" text="%startup_title">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" top="5.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
         </Label>
    </top>
   <center>
      <VBox fx:id="vbox" >
         <children>
            <ProgressBar fx:id="progressBar" prefWidth="500.0" progress="0.0"  />
            <Label fx:id="progressLabel" styleClass="item-title" text="tt" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The issue seems to that the vbox has a with of entire screen, and items inside are on top_left. I understand I need to set the width of the vbox to minimum instead of letting it expands in the borderpane, but how ??

Thank you !

Comment: `alignment="CENTER"`?

Comment: Yes, thank you,I wonder how I missed it in the scene builder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383821/how-do-you-specify-that-you-want-your-elements-in-a-toolbar-to-be-centered) : simply add alignment="CENTER" in the fxml...

This is not really what I wanted but this is enough